# In SQL how can I get a mathematical expression to give me a double instead of a truncated int?

Tags: sql, math, double, int

I am performing some math in an SQL select statement but the number is always truncated to an int. How can I make it give me a double/float value?

Example:

`select top 10 id, (select COUNT(*) from table1 / 100) from table2`

If the value was 92.738 I just get 92

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? I'm guessing SQL Server from use of `top`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering integer division. You need to ensure one of the operands is not an integer. e.g. as below.

```
select top 10 id, (select COUNT(*) / 100.0 from table1) from table2
```

Comment: Ah, duh. I was thinking i needed to use some Double() method or something. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you can use Cast(Count(*) as float) * CAST(100 as float), but the answer below does the same thing